# GASでは日本語名フォルダが作成できない？

Tags: google-apps-script

GASでフォルダ作成に際し、フォルダ名がAlphabetの場合は正しく作成されますが、漢字またはひらがなの場合は作成される場合もあれば、作成されない場合もあります。作成されない場合でも右側パネルには子フォルダ、孫フォルダが表示されます。　これはGASが日本語に対応していないからでしょうか？　下にサンプルコードを記します。　追テストをして頂けると幸いです。
また何か対応策があれば、是非教えてください。

```
function createFoldersTest1() {
  var folder1 = DriveApp.createFolder('JAPAN'); 
  var folder2 = folder1.createFolder('TOHOKU');
  folder2.createFolder('Aomori');
  folder2.createFolder('Akita');
  folder2.createFolder('Iwate');
  folder2.createFolder('Yamagata');
  folder2.createFolder('MIyagi');
  folder2.createFolder('Fukushima');
  folder2.createFolder('Nigata');
  folder2.createFolder('Gunma');
}

function createFoldersTest2() {
  var folder1 = DriveApp.createFolder('日本国'); 
  var folder2 = folder1.createFolder('東北地方');
  folder2.createFolder('青森県');
  folder2.createFolder('秋田県');
  folder2.createFolder('岩手県');
  folder2.createFolder('山形県');
  folder2.createFolder('宮城県');
  folder2.createFolder('福島県');
  folder2.createFolder('新潟県');
  folder2.createFolder('群馬県');
}

function createFoldersTest3() {
  var folder1 = DriveApp.createFolder('あいうえお'); 
  var folder2 = folder1.createFolder('かきくけこ');
  folder2.createFolder('さしすせそ');
  folder2.createFolder('たちつてと');
  folder2.createFolder('なにぬねの');
  folder2.createFolder('はひふへほ');
  folder2.createFolder('まみむめも');
  folder2.createFolder('やいゆえよ');
  folder2.createFolder('らりるれろ');
  folder2.createFolder('わいうえお');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

上記のテストコードを試してみましたがすべて作成されました。
GASの場合、各メソッドの呼び出しから、画面上表示されないケースが有ります。

また特定の文字列のみ不可能な場合はGoogle側のバグの可能性があるので以下よりissue登録したほうが良いです。

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list